# How to emulate the live lyrics animated gradient in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, gradient

It's probably very complicated but would appreciate if someone could lead me in the right direction. I would like to create a flowing gradient animation like the one in the music app. I want to use it to change colours depending on lights for a smart home app. I am familiar with using `LinearGradient` and animating the start and end points, but this is obviously a lot more complicated but hopefully someone knows what I can do.

I found a [MPUGradientView](https://developer.limneos.net/?ios=13.1.3&framework=MediaPlayerUI.framework&header=MPUGradientView.h) header that includes `CAGradientLayer` so I'm not sure if its combining gradients to somehow create the effect.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you had any progress with this? I'm looking to create something very similar. I've messed around with some automatically generating paths, to create the patterns of lines for the gradients and that's about it. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @TahmidAzam Check my latest answer. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up getting something quite close in mostly SwiftUI but it requires an image.

Here is a preview of what it looks like:
https://twitter.com/priva2804/status/1284439692352434178?s=21

Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/Priva28/22fbae9dbe04a08fadf748793dd23d00

Comment: This is amazing work! Thank you very much - I'm thinking I can create a view of a linear gradient using SwiftUI, then export it to an image somehow and pass it into this - hopefully I can get it to work.

Comment: No problem I’m glad it helps. If you can’t find a way to do it in swiftui you could always create a helper that applies a CAGradientLayer over a UIImage then add the UIImage to the SwiftUI image with something like `Image(uiImage: myGradient)`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly reproducing the screenshot you were asking for, but it should get you started.
Inspired from here: https://nerdyak.tech/development/2019/09/30/animating-gradients-swiftui.html

```
struct MainView: View {

@State var gradient = [Color.red, Color.purple, Color.orange]

@State var startPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
@State var endPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 2)

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: self.gradient), startPoint: self.startPoint, endPoint: self.endPoint)
            .overlay(
                Text("Hello world")
        )
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 6).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
            self.startPoint = UnitPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
            self.endPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        }
    }
}}
```